# How to check if a terminal can display undercurl from within a bash/zsh script?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, tput

How to check if a terminal can display undercurl from within a bash/zsh script?

In a recent project I used undercurl escape sequence for output printed by a zsh script. It works well in modern terminals, but Apple's Terminal.app shows that as a reversed background-foreground. It would be nice to be able to detect if the terminal has the ability to display undercurl, and only then use undercurl or default to regular underline.

Answer (score 4):

Undercurl as available on a few terminals such as mintty or vte, and apparently originally from [kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/underlines/) is enabled by the `Smulx` extended terminfo capability (`s`et `m`ode `u`nder`l`ine e`x`tended).

On a system with a recent version of the `terminfo` database (or at least for its entry for the terminal you're interested in as sometimes, `terminfo` entry are shipped alongside the terminal emulator they describe), you can see it in the definition if you run `infocmp` with the `-x` option:

```
$ infocmp -1 -x vte | grep Smulx
        Smulx=\E[4:%p1%dm,
```

The `p1` parameter there is the type of extended `u`nder`l`ine, 0 for no underscore, 1 for normal underline, 2 for double underline, 3 for curly underline, 4 for dotted underscore and 5 for dashed underscore.

The escape sequence to set the underline colour is in the `setal` extended capability, though looking at the `infocmp` latest devel version of ncurses, I see significant difference between kitty and mintty escape sequences (I doubt mintty's `setal=\E[5%p1%dm` is right).

The `Smulx` terminfo capability being available for the current terminal (as identified by the `$TERM`¹), though not guaranteeing it, would be a strong indication that the terminal supports undercurl.

In any case, it's all fairly new stuff, which doesn't seem fully stabilised, you'll likely need to wait a few years for the changes to permeate to the terminfo databases of all systems.

Looking at iTerm2 specifically, the terminfo sources in the very latest development version of ncurses claims to describe what iTerm2 3.0.15 was supporting. There's no mention of `Smulx` in that one.

`iTerm2` sources do include [a terminfo source file](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/d3156dcc75222cd84808ddadd782c28b21829734/Resources/xterm-terminfo), but it does redefine the entries for `xterm` instead of defining on for `iTerm2` (!?). It does define a [`Smulx` capability](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/d3156dcc75222cd84808ddadd782c28b21829734/Resources/xterm-terminfo#L1696) but defines a [`Setulc` capability](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/d3156dcc75222cd84808ddadd782c28b21829734/Resources/xterm-terminfo#L1699) instead of `setal` for the underline colour.

In `zsh`, you can test for the presence of a capability in the terminfo entry for the current terminal with:

```
if (( $+terminfo[Smulx] )); then 
  echoti Smulx 3
  print Smulx is available
  if (( $+terminfo[setal] )); then
    echoti setal 1
    print Setting the underline colour is also possible.
  fi
  echoti Smulx 0
else
  print no support according to terminfo
fi
```

If you can't rely on the terminfo database, or on `$TERM` pointing to the right entry in there, you can try and identify the terminal emulator by querying it. A few terminals will answer some identifying sequence when sent `\e[>c`.

For instance:

```
{
  saved=$(stty -g)
  stty -echo -icanon min 1 time 10
  printf '\e[>c'
  IFS='>;' read -rd c ignore type version rom ignore
  stty "$saved"
} <> /dev/tty 1>&0
```

Would store three numbers that should help you recognise the terminal. For instance, I find that `tmux` returns 84 for `$type`, but seems to return 0 for the other 2. `screen` returns 83 for `$type` and an encoding of its version  in `$version`. Same with kitty (4000) or vte-based terminals (65).

undercurl support was added to vte in 0.51.2, so if `$type` is 65 and `$version` is >= 5102 for instance, that tells you undercurl should be supported (assuming there's no other terminal emulator that chose 65 as their identifier).

---

<sup>¹ see also how on Debian at least, `gnome-terminal` sets `$TERM` to `xterm-256color` instead of `vte-256color` not letting applications know about all the extra things `gnome-terminal`/`vte` can do (see `infocmp -x vte-256color xterm-256color` for the differences)</sup>

Comment: Doesn't work for iTerm2. It displays under curl with ``printf "\e[4:3mhello\e[0m"``, but ``echoti Smulx 3`` returns ``echoti: no such terminfo capability: Smulx``. Same with tmux, it is able to print that but does not recognize Smulx. Seems like terminal emulators and tmux are doing something different. Also, ``$+terminfo[Smulx]`` is 0 for iterm2 as well as tmux

Comment: @reportaman, that would mean you have an out of date `terminfo` database. If you get and compile the latest from https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html (you'll see there `Smulx` was added to the `tmux` entry in 2018) and find it's still missing some, you can report it to the maintainer (@ThomasDickey, who's active here).

Comment: Thanks, running that second listing gives me error ``stty: 'standard input': unable to perform all requested operations`` inside tmux, but no error when run outside tmux in same terminal emulator. Btw, its offtopic, but is there a way to upgrade those terminfos? invisible island website is a little difficult to navigate, I never found a way to update all of the terminfos from command line. Ideally something that would merge with existing user's edits... Am on macOS ARM64.

Comment: @reportaman *"unable to perform all requested operations"*. I can't explain why it would work differently inside and outside tmux